# How can I get the Top Tier Energy Weapons without the Van Graffs?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So, I completed Heartache By The Number in a peaceful way and got attacked by the Van Graff thugs, as you're pretty much supposed to be, outside the Atomic Wrangler while turning in the Debt Collector quest. Now, I had been trying to wait to turn in the Heartache by the Number quest because I wanted to get the higher tier Energy Weaps (the 20k-ish ones) from them and now they're permanently hostile.

The question is, is there any one way to get the top-tier energy weapons that doesn't involve them? Keep in mind, I'm on the PS3 so I can't just make them neutral with me again to fix the hostility issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Gloria Van Graff is killed, the two unique weapons she sells are instead sold by the Gun Runners' vendortron. This allows you to still acquire the weapons if you piss her off.

Unfortunately, if she is hostile but alive, there is no way to buy those guns. You need to either kill her or to use slightly weaker weapons.

Comment: Once she's dead, how long does it take the vendortron to start giving up the good stuff?