# Why can't I get the unique Energy Weapons?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In an [earlier question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147651/how-can-i-get-the-top-tier-energy-weapons-without-the-van-graffs) I asked how one could get the unique energy weapons providing one had already completed Heartache By The Number. I was told that if you killed Gloria Van Graff the items *should* turn up in the Gunrunner's inventory shortly thereafter.

I seem to have run into a problem with that scenario. It has been an unknown, but presumably rather large, amount of in game days since I killed Gloria and her brother... and still no unique energy weapons in the Gunrunner store. You'd think they'd be more cooperative considering I stopped their manufacturing specs from being leaked...

Since killing Gloria didn't work is there ***any*** other way to get the unique energy weapons or am I SOL?

Comment: Fallout Wiki cites it as a known bug that occasionally the Vendortron's stock won't add the Van Graff weapons. Sadly, the only fix is the dev console.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz this should be an answer.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz make that an actual answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

[LessPop said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150093/why-cant-i-get-the-unique-energy-weapons/354272#comment202503_150093):

> The Fallout Wiki cites it as a known bug that occasionally the Vendortron's stock won't add the Van Graff weapons. Sadly, the only fix is the dev console.